# error when running script in console with argparse

Tags: python

hello made this program that is right here on this page but the codes are but when executing the script in the ubuntun console it gives me the following problem

```
from math import radians,cos,sin,asin,sqrt,atan2
import argparse


parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--lat1',type=float,metavar="",required=True, help="enter the first latitude")
parser.add_argument('--lon1',type=float,metavar="",required=True,help="enter the first length")
parser.add_argument('--lat2',type=float,metavar="",required=True,help="enter the second latitude")
parser.add_argument('--lon2',type=float,metavar="",required=True,help="enter the second length")
args=parser.parse_args()   
    
def python_distance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2):
    lat1=abs(radians(lat1))
    lon1=abs(radians(lon1))
    lat2=abs(radians(lat2))
    lon2=abs(radians(lon2))
    
    radio=6371.0
    delta_lon=lon2-lon1
    delta_lat=lat2-lat1
    h=sin(delta_lat/2)**2+cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*sin(delta_lon/2)**2
    t=2*atan2(sqrt(h),sqrt(1-h))
    distancia=radio*t
    return distancia

if __name__=="_main_":
    print python_distance(args.lat1,args.lon1,args.lat2,args.lon2)
```

if I try the function it gives me exactly the distance but when executing the script it tells me the following

```
yeferson@yeff:~/Escritorio$ python wha.py -13.594787 -89.827362 -13.966572 -88.891292

usage: wha.py [-h] --lat1  --lon1  --lat2  --lon2

wha.py: error: argument --lat1 is required
```

something is failing me in the arguments, I could wait for your help in this problem

Comment: Argument with `--` is optional argument and need to input like `--lat1 -13.594787`. As all your optional argument are required, you may just remove all the `--` and they are now positional arguments and you can just input `-13.594787`.

Comment: Besides, `_main_` should be `__main__` (double underscore on both sides), and `print` is missing `()`.

Comment: @Adamkwm thank you and to avoid for the sign - what do I do

Comment: what do you mean? aren't your arguments negative numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
python wha.py --lat1=-13.594787 --lon1=-89.827362 --lat2=-13.966572 --lon2=-88.891292
```

Comment: thank you and to avoid for the sign "- "what do I do